# Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String' to an array?

Tags: ios, swift

Total new beginner here in Swift, I'm trying to understand typecasting here

I have the below code

```swift
    @IBAction func randomImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageList", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
        
        let data = dict!.object(forKey: "Images") as! [String]
        
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: data.randomElement())
        
    }
```

As shown above, first I have `dict!` to ensure that `dict` is available, then `data` will be typecasted into `[String]` which is an array of string.

Now the part that I dont understand is why `data.randomElement()` giving me error

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

> Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'

> Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

sure enough based on the suggestion, i can get away with `data.randomElement()!`, but why is that needed?

Comment: Learn how to unwrap an optional value.  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: `randomElement()` must return an optional because there's no guarantee that you called it on a non-empty array. If you called it on an empty array, it returns `nil`.

Comment: @Alexander: Ah I see, if `randomElement()` must return an `optional` then it make sense, thanks!

Comment: @Isaac This is also the case for `first`, `last`, `min()`, `max()`, etc.

Comment: @Isaac Here is the document. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `randomElement()` function returns an Optional because the collection you are fetching from might be empty. if it is, the function returns nil.

**Get out of the habit of using the `!` force-unwrap operator (and variants like implicitly unwrapped optionals.)** I call `!` the "crash-if-nil" operator. That's what it does.

You should rewrite your code using `if let` syntax (optional binding)

```
@IBAction func randomImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageList", ofType: "plist"),
      let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path),
      let data = dict.object(forKey: "Images") as? [String],
      let image = UIImage(named: data.randomElement()) {
        imageView.image = image
    } else {
         // Unable to load image
    }
}
```

With a compound `if let` like that the expression quits on each step if the result is nil. If the result is valid, it keeps going on the if statement and the new temporary variable is now a non-optional.

Once you make it through the last let in the compound if let, you have a UIImage in `image` that you can install into your image view.

If any of the steps fail, the else clause runs. you can do whatever you want there - install a default image, install nil into the imageView to remove it, print to the console, whatever. (Although you could simplify the code a little if you were going to install a nil image into the image view.)

---

### Edit:

In addition to `if let` optional binding, you can also use guard statements.

`if let` optional binding says "try to unwrap this optional/optionals. If it succeeds, create a variable that's only defined inside the body of the if statement, and execute the if statement.

In contrast, `guard` says "try to unwrap this optional/optionals. If it succeeds, continue. If it fails, execute a block of code that exits the current scope.

Guard statements are useful when you need to check a whole series o things and want to keep going when everything is good, but bail out when if something goes wrong.

`if let` optional binding can lead to ever-increasing levels of indentation:

```
func foo() {
    if let a = anOpitonal {
       // Do stuff
       if let b = a.someOtherOptional {
          // Do more stuff
          if let c = b.yetAnotherOptional {
              // Still more code that only runs if all 3 unwraps work
          }
       }
    }
}
```

In contrast, you could write that with guard like this:

```
func foo() {
    guard let a = anOpitonal else { return }
    // Do stuff

    guard let b = a.someOtherOptional else { return }

    // Do more stuff
    guard let c = b.yetAnotherOptional  else { return }

    // Still more code that only runs if all 3 guard statements work
}
```